# Concatenating a string to a slice of structs

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm trying to create an endpoint Go API to be consumed by front end JavaScript graphing library.

What should happen:

1. /data endpoint to get an array of JSON data.
2. The data is just a slice of go structs, just two in this example but it will be over 10000.
3. The graphing library expects additional meta data. It's saved as a variable called AdditionalInfo.
4. The problem is when I want to encode the AdditionalInfo + AllAgents it won't let me join a string with a slice of structs.
5. At the end of the slice of structs there also needs to be ]` to make it valid JSON

Problems:

1. How do you add additional data at the front and back the slice of structs?
2. Is appending a struct to a slice of structs efficient?
3. Would it be better to create a slice with a known length and then use range to append to it?

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "encoding/json"
       "fmt"
       "log"
       "net/http"
       "os"
   )

   func main() {
       port := os.Getenv("PORT")
       if port == "" {
           port = "443"
           log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
       }

       http.HandleFunc("/data", TrySnipped)
       log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))

   }

   func TrySnipped(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
       var AllAgents []SingleAgent
       AllAgents = append(AllAgents, FirstAgent)
       AllAgents = append(AllAgents, SecondAgent)

       json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(AllAgents)

   }

   var AdditionalInfo = `"meta": {
               "page": 1,
               "pages": 1,
               "perpage": -1,
               "total": 350,
               "sort": "asc",
               "field": "RecordID"
           },
           "data": [`

   type SingleAgent struct {
       RecordID             string `json:"RecordID"`
       OldEmployeeID        string `json:"OldEmployeeID"`
       NewEmployeeID        string `json:"NewEmployeeID"`
       AgentRank            int    `json:"AgentRank"`
       AgentName            string `json:"AgentName"`
       AgentEmail           string `json:"AgentEmail"`
       TeamManager          string `json:"TeamManager"`
       LineOfBusiness       string `json:"LineOfBusiness"`
       FitnessCampStartDate string `json:"FitnessCampStartDate"`
       FitnessCampEndDate   string `json:"FitnessCampEndDate"`
       FitnessCampStatus    int    `json:"FitnessCampStatus"`
       AgentFitnessRank     int    `json:"AgentFitnessRank"`
       LatestMetricA        int    `json:"MetricA"`
       LatestMetricB        int    `json:"MetricB"`
       LatestMetricC        int    `json:"MetricC"`
       LatestMetricD        int    `json:"MetricD"`
       LatestMetricE        int    `json:"MetricD"`
       SiteName             string `json:"SiteName"`
       SiteID               string `json:"SiteID"`
       PostCampWeek1        string `json:"PostCampWeek1"`
       PostCampWeek2        string `json:"PostCampWeek2"`
       PostCampWeek3        string `json:"PostCampWeek3"`
   }

   var FirstAgent = SingleAgent{
       RecordID:             "30",
       OldEmployeeID:        "785114544",
       NewEmployeeID:        "10785114544",
       AgentRank:            3,
       AgentName:            "Shandeigh Rawsen",
       AgentEmail:           "shandeigh.rawsen@gmail.com",
       TeamManager:          "Oliver Lamplugh",
       LineOfBusiness:       "BMS",
       FitnessCampStartDate: "8/13/2018",
       FitnessCampEndDate:   "10/7/2018",
       FitnessCampStatus:    1,
       AgentFitnessRank:     1,
       LatestMetricA:        77,
       LatestMetricB:        167,
       LatestMetricC:        496,
       LatestMetricD:        72,
       LatestMetricE:        80,
       SiteName:             "Montreal",
       SiteID:               "4",
       PostCampWeek1:        "10/2/2018",
       PostCampWeek2:        "10/9/2018",
       PostCampWeek3:        "10/19/2018",
   }
   var SecondAgent = SingleAgent{
       RecordID:             "29",
       OldEmployeeID:        "980433290",
       NewEmployeeID:        "10980433290",
       AgentRank:            4,
       AgentName:            "Terrijo Dewberry",
       AgentEmail:           "terrijo.deberry@gmail.com",
       TeamManager:          "Oliver Lamplugh",
       LineOfBusiness:       "BTSW",
       FitnessCampStartDate: "7/28/2018",
       FitnessCampEndDate:   "9/23/2018",
       FitnessCampStatus:    2,
       AgentFitnessRank:     2,
       LatestMetricA:        88,
       LatestMetricB:        92,
       LatestMetricC:        716,
       LatestMetricD:        78,
       LatestMetricE:        66,
       SiteName:             "Montreal",
       SiteID:               "2",
       PostCampWeek1:        "10/2/2018",
       PostCampWeek2:        "10/9/2018",
       PostCampWeek3:        "10/15/2018",
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the additional info, the agents and the closing brace to the response:

```
 io.WriteString(w, "{")
 io.WriteString(w, AdditionalInfo)
 json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(AllAgents)
 io.WriteString(w, "]}")  // closing ] for data and closing } for root
```

Note this encodes two levels of `[ ]` around the agents. It's unclear if that's what you want.

An alternate approach is to create a Go value matching the structure of the output and encode that:

```
v := map[string]interface{}{
    "meta": map[string]interface{}{
        "page":    1,
        "pages":   1,
        "perpage": -1,
        "total":   350,
        "sort":    "asc",
        "field":   "RecordID",
    },
    "data": AllAgents,
 }
 if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(v); err != nil {
    // handle error
 }
```

Again, it's unclear how much nesting you want around agents. You may need this variation:

```
v := map[string]interface{}{
    "meta": map[string]interface{}{
        "page":    1,
        "pages":   1,
        "perpage": -1,
        "total":   350,
        "sort":    "asc",
        "field":   "RecordID",
    },
    "data": []interface{}{AllAgents},
 }
 if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(v); err != nil {
    // handle error
 }
```

re: Efficiency Creating a slice of the final size is generally more efficient then incrementally growing the slice with `append`.  There may be some efficenty gained by using  a slice of pointers `[]*SingleAgent` instead of the slice of struct values `[]SingleAgent`.